# No intellisense in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, resharper, asp.net-core

After installing ASP.Net Core via Visual Studio ==> New Project ==> Web ==> ASP.Net Web Application ==> OK ==> ASP.Net 5 Templates. Restarted the system after the installation then create a new project of ASP.NET 5 Template ==> Empty website. I dont get any intellisense and all class names are in RED as if the Visual Studio or Resharper is unable to locate the definition.

Here are some screen shots.
[image]

and no intellisense

[image]

When using services object, I was expecting services.AddSingleton, service.AddScoped services.AddTransient  service.AddLogging and so on...

I have restarted the visual studio but still the same result, however the project compiles and runs as expected but its very difficult to figure out the new api without any support from the intellisense.

I have resharper v 9 with update 1 installed.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you disable Reshaper? Just in case that it may not support the new project types and only supports the old *.csproj ones

Comment: If you didn't install the latest bits from http://get.asp.net, I am not surprised to see any issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying... 
I will try to disable Resharper and will get back to you. Meanwhile, I uninstalled ASP.Net core / ASP.Net 5 from my laptop (where this issue is) and reinstalled it from [GET.ASP.NET](https://get.asp.net/) but still the same result. On my Desktop machine however, it looks all good so no issues with that. Now only the difference that I can see is that on my laptop (where this issue is) I have .Net Framework v4.6.1 installed which is not on my desktop machine.

Comment: Did you get this working with RC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends what version of ASP.NET 5 you're using, as it's been a bit of a moving target to support. It should work, but for (I think) RC1 bits, but if you're trying to use the current pre-RC2 builds, there are known issues (e.g. the tooling has been completely rewritten). We're hoping to get things fixed and updated post RC2, but with the recent announcements about continuing breaking changes to the tooling (project.json is being phased out and replaced with .csproj files), this might not be so easy. We're going to have to wait and see how the RC2 tooling looks.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with .NET Core and disabling Resharper worked for me. As soon as I disabled it, Intellisense in Razor views started working again.