# Bootstrap Intellisense not working in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I'm working on a project that is made in part and I was asked to complete it, it's in ASP.net Core, the people that used to work with it made references to `bootstrap cdn` inside the `_Layout` view like this:

```
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I've commented those reference and I've been trying to add it in project.json but once added it doesn't appear under the `lib` folder. Bootstrap is working but there is not intellisense what makes difficult to work with it, could we add a reference to cdn but not to the minified version? Why when I add it to project.json it's not added to `lib` folder under wwwroot?

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? Try disabling it and restarting visual studio to see if that fixes it. Found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38250234/1804496

Comment: @Zack I don't have it installed

Comment: Are you familiar with `npm` or `bower` packages? I use `bootstrap` with `npm`. Then, I move it into wwwroot folder using a `gruntjs` task

Comment: If you add bootstrap in project.json, you're adding it as a nuget package. So, you need to copy your bootstrap files (css, js, fonts) from your nuget folder (C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.nuget\packages\bootstrap) to your wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a separated ASP.net Core project, included bootstrap in project.json and copied the generated `bootstrap` file to the application I'm working inside the `lib` folder. No I have `bootstrap Intellisense`.

Comment: the intellisense works only if the directory in the .bowerrc is wwwroot/lib. It not if we change to bower_components for example and delete the lib inside the wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue where I installed VS 2022 and bootstrap 5 with no IntelliSense. I cater this problem by installing the previous 4.0.6 version of bootstrap where I got IntelliSense.

One more suggestion is to write bootstrap in other editor and copy that to VS if you are really concern about bootstrap 5.
Hopefully this would help